# Unable to access datadog trace-agent port

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, datadog

I'm currently running a Ruby on Rails app on Google Kubernetes Engine and have deployed datadog but am having issues connecting to the trace agent.

Any ideas?

```
E, [2020-07-22T01:13:54.773686 #6] ERROR -- ddtrace: [ddtrace] (/usr/local/bundle/gems/ddtrace-0.37.0/lib/ddtrace/transport/http/client.rb:35:in `rescue in send_request') Internal error during HTTP transport request. Cause: Failed to open TCP connection to 10.128.0.9:8126 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "10.128.0.9" port 8126) Location: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:949:in `rescue in block in connect'
```

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: Provide more information. Whats your GKE cluster version (or you are using GCE and build Kubeadm cluster?). How did you deployed datadog? Did you configure firewall?